# Compiling OpenCV code in Java

Tags: java, opencv

I am new to java so maybe this is a little stupid. I have written a C++ code that uses OpenCV, now I want to convert it to Java. I used to compile C++ code in the terminal using

```
g++ main.cpp -o main `pkg-config opencv --libs`
```

but I am unable to find a simple equivalent for java. I have tried using

```
javac -cp .:/usr/share/java/opencv.jar OpenCVDemo.java
```

but this gives a compilation error which looks like as if it was unable to link to the library. What I am looking for is a way to compile the opencv Java code in a way similar to the C++ method.

It would be helpful if someone could demonstrate how to compile this code

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

public class Hello
{
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
      Mat mat = Mat.eye( 3, 3, CvType.CV_8UC1 );
      System.out.println( "mat = " + mat.dump() );
   }
}
```

I have only been able to find ways to configure an IDE to compile the program or using `ant` or `sbt`. What I want is a way to compile the program from the command line using only `javac`.

Comment: This might help you out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873017/where-to-get-the-jar-for-opencv

Comment: This tutorial shows how use java version of openCV under Netbeans. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/717283/How-to-Use-OpenCV-with-Java-under-NetBeans-IDE 
I have configured my env in this way and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out myself

Compiling:

```
javac -cp .:/usr/share/OpenCV/java/opencv-248.jar Hello.java
```

Executing

```
java -cp .:/usr/share/OpenCV/java/opencv-248.jar Hello
```

I think I was using the incorrect `jar` file