# Can't find .jar file after installing OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv

I have installed OpenCv-3.1.0 in ubuntu-14.04. When I check the installation by typing "pkg-config --modversion opencv", I get the output as "3.1.0". I think that means installation is successful.
I want to use it in IntelliJ IDEA. I'm trying to add the .jar file as a library. But opencv.jar file can not be found in the bin folder.

Comment: If the installation is successful the .jar file should be under bin folder. May be check for any installation issues

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873017/where-to-get-the-jar-for-opencv

Comment: I don't think the main OpenCV package includes the respective Java bindings.

Comment: @E_net4 yes you are correct. You must specify it with the flag `--with-java`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installation can be done as in [this link](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation). Even after installing properly, I couldn't find the needed jar file.

I was able to fix this issue by installing "Apache Ant" and proceeded again with "cmake" and "make" commands.

I think this happens because OpenCV is in C/C++ and I need it in Java. Apache Ant is a Java library and command-line tool and can also be used effectively to build non Java applications, for instance C or C++ applications.
That helped to build the needed jar file.

Answer (score 1):

You may have forgotten to specify the `--with-java` parameter

`brew tap homebrew/science
 brew install opencv --with-java`

After compiling, a jar file should be in the path

`/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/share/OpenCV/java/opencv-249.jar`

For those not using mac OS X, you could try this:

`brew install ant
 brew edit opencv`

Add `-DBUILD_opencv_java=ON` to the args array.

`brew install opencv`

Comment: @E_net4 see my revised answer where it says "For those not on mac OS X"

Comment: You must be confused. Not only would this never solve my problem, it is also not my question.