# Installed opencv but now can't find .jar file to be able to use it in java

Tags: java, eclipse, file, opencv, jar

I installed opencv-3.2.0 on my mac os x 10.9, 
but now when I try to add an external JAR to my eclipse I am unable to find the .jar file that should be in the opencv I installed. 
I have a feeling that should have done something to enable it to work for java, does anyone know of a way to fix this and find/get the .jar file?

I have followed other methods such as:

https://udallascs.wordpress.com/2014/03/30/adding-opencv-and-configuring-to-work-with-eclipse-and-java/

However I still have no luck find a .jar file in Vision/opencv/build/bin

I think I might be missing a java dependency because when I follow this tutorial:

http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d9/d52/tutorial_java_dev_intro.html

and on the step where I type:

```
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..
```

Java isn't listed in to build.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to get the jar for openCV?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873017/where-to-get-the-jar-for-opencv)

Comment: thanks I'll give it a go!

Comment: still no luck finding .jar :(